# Determine if table exists in SQL Server CE?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I know this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/sql-server-check-if-table-exists), but I'm using SQL Server CE 3.5 with a WinForms project in C#.  How can I determine whether a table exists?  I know the `IF` keyword is not supported, though `EXISTS` is.  Does information_schema exist in CE where I can query against it?  Thanks.

Comment: I thought I had a nifty implementation of just what code was needed for this, but it's not working for me. I posted a question 

diesbezueglich at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ee6aefa-e47b-4f0c-8735-120b8bf041ec/why-is-my-sqlserver-ce-code-failing (I tried to post it on codeproject, but it froze on me multiple times)

Comment: Third time was a charm: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/629607/Why-is-my-SQLServer-CE-code-failing
Yes, I cross-posted, but to two different forums, so hopefully that is not considered gauche.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, it does exist:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

Comment: Wouldn't "SELECT COUNT(ID)" be easier and a little more performant (in case the table is wide (many columns) or tall (many rows)?

Comment: It really depends on how you want to code around it. If you just want to check existence, then yeah. I just wanted to demonstrate that INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES is available can be queried. The rest is basic SQL.

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari Go Persians!!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can Query the Table and catch the Exception thrown.
If there is an Exception, the Table wasn't found, else the Table exists.

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TableName;
```

A little and simple Performance Test had better Results than the Query against INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Although I would consider a Query against INFORMATION_SCHEMA as cleaner.

Comment: If the table doesn't exist, that method will throw an exception, so you shouldn't do that - catching an exception is never the way to go when there is a clean alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Using Database helper:

```
var db = Database.Open("MyDatabase");
var sql = @"SELECT Count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'"
var count = db.QueryValue(sql);
if(count.Equals(1)){
    //table exists
}
```