# SQL query doesn't not work in SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

How to use `insert into ... where ( .. )` in SQL Server ce?

This query:

```
insert into table(field) values(@val) 
where not exists (select field from table where field = @code);
```

returns

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 40,Token in error = where ]

How I fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE (...)`

Comment: @todda.speot.is: That is valid syntax, but would end up repeating the insert for every row in the table that matches the query.

Comment: @competent_tech Unless SQL CE is different (I know it is in places), the omission of the `FROM` clause prevents that scenario.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: yes, that is perfectly valid syntax in CE. However, it doesn't address the question, which is: how do I only insert into the table if a specific condition in the database is met.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do this the old-fashioned way: select the record in question from the database and, if it does not exist, perform the insert.

[Here's a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174633%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to the relevant MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that your issue is the "NOT EXISTS", as SQL CE just doesn't support that.  Here's a link to a similar question that might help: [“If not exists” fails on SQL CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652867/if-not-exists-fails-on-sql-ce)