# How can I use IF EXISTS in SQL to check if a record is retrieved?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

The below code should check if the record exists, then either update it or add a new record if there isn't one to start. However it fails to parse the SQL query. Any thoughts?

```
var db = Database.Open("DB2");

var save = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM QuestionnaireData WHERE ID=" + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId + ") UPDATE QuestionnaireData SET Q1=" + "TEST" + " WHERE ID=" + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId + " ELSE INSERT INTO QuestionnaireData VALUES (@0, @1)";        

db.Execute(save, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, "TEST");
```

Error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token
>   line offset = 1,Token in error = IF ]
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: There was
>   an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset
>   = 1,Token in error = IF ]
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 16:                 var save = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM
>   QuestionnaireData WHERE ID=" + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId + ") UPDATE
>   QuestionnaireData SET Q1='" + "TEST" + "' WHERE ID=" +
>   WebSecurity.CurrentUserId + " ELSE INSERT INTO QuestionnaireData
>   VALUES (@0, @1)";         Line 17:  Line 18:
>   db.Execute(save, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, "TEST"); Line 19:  Line
>   20:
>
> Source File: c:\Users\Blake\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\WebSites\MBM\Questionnaire\BasicInfo.cshtml    Line: 18
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlCeException (0x80004005): There was an error parsing the query. [
>   Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = IF ]]
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr) +136
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan() +798
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options) +363
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +53
>   WebMatrix.Data.Database.Execute(String commandText, Object[] args)
>   +115    ASP._Page_Questionnaire_BasicInfo_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Blake\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\WebSites\MBM\Questionnaire\BasicInfo.cshtml:18
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1
>   executors) +68    System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>   +151    System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17    System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +62
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +114
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212

Updated code:

```
var check = "SELECT count(*) FROM QuestionnaireData WHERE ID=" + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

if (db.Execute(check) == 0)
{
    var insert = "INSERT INTO QuestionnaireData VALUES (@0, @1)";
    db.Execute(insert, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, "TEST");
}
else {
    var update = "UPDATE QuestionnaireData SET Q1='" + "TEST" + "' WHERE ID=" + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
    db.Execute(update);
};
```

Comment: "it crashes"? What does that mean?

Comment: @Blorgbeard There was an error parsing the query.

Comment: Try printing the value of `save` before you try to execute it. The problem should be clear enough.

Comment: The value of save is just a string. I can't print the result of the query because it fails to parse and thus doesn't execute.

Comment: Yes. Print the value of save and *look at it*.

Comment: I did print it, it shows exactly what is above with the current user's ID plugged in. I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: OK, another hint: does it have quotes around everything that should be quoted?

Comment: I'm VERY new to SQL in general, I've seen examples online doing something similar and in some they had parts of it quoted and in others they did not. So I'm really not sure if anything should be.

Comment: What is the rule for SQL that determines if something should be wrapped in quotes or not?

Comment: I tried wrapping both IDs and the data I'm trying to update with quotes but I still have the same issue.

Comment: I've posted an answer, hopefully it explains the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** Since you're using SQL Server CE:

SQL Server CE [does not support IF statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652867/if-not-exists-fails-on-sql-ce). You'll have to execute

```
SELECT count(*) FROM QuestionnaireData WHERE ID=123
```

by itself. Then check the result, and either execute your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement.

**End edit**: Original syntax error problem:

You are ending up with SQL that looks like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM QuestionnaireData WHERE ID=123) 
    UPDATE QuestionnaireData SET Q1=TEST WHERE ID=123 
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO QuestionnaireData VALUES (@0, @1)
```

Your problem is `SET Q1=TEST` - TEST is clearly a string, so it should be quoted: `SET Q1='TEST'`

Note that you need to use single quotes for strings in SQL, rather than double quotes like in C#.

So, you need to make a change to your C# code something like this:

```
var save = "... SET Q1='" + "TEST" + "' WHERE ...";
```

Note the single quotes have been added. I've left your double-quotes in, since I assume you had some reason for that - replacing TEST with a variable later?

Of course, if you do that, you should really just use another parameter instead.

Comment: I tried the above and it doesn't seem to change anything. And yes, I just put TEST in quotes for the purpose of the question, it will be a variable in the program.

Comment: Ah, you're using SQL Server CE - it has limited features compared to full-blown SQL Server. This is one of them

Comment: Yes I am, I'm sorry I didn't mention that, I didn't realize it was relevant. Is there an alternative for SQL Server CE for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes perfect sense now.

Comment: One last question. When evaluating the result of the first statement what do I check for? Will it be a null if nothing is found?

Comment: I added a note to my question with the code I have now, something still doesn't seem to work right. It doesn't break but nothing ever writes to the database, regardless of if the record is there or not.

Comment: The result of the first statement should be a number - `0` meaning no rows found, `1` meaning the row was found. I think you'll need to use `QuerySingle` instead of `Execute`, though. I'm not sure about why nothing is updating. It certainly looks like one of the statements should execute, and *something* should be written to the database. Perhaps you should ask a new question about it; this one is getting full :P

Comment: Alright, I'll mess around with it some more and if all else fails come back and ask another question. Thanks again for the tips!