# Create a table if it does not exist?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, .net-core, .net-standard

Using Entity Framework Core, is there a way to create the table if it does not yet exist? Exception will throw even if `EnsureCreated` is called in the context:

```
DbSet<Ticker> Ticker { get; set }
Database.EnsureCreated();

Ticker.Add(...);
dbctx.SaveChanges(); <== exception
```

Results in exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Ticker'

Is there a way to create the table `Ticker` before data is inserted?

== EDIT==

This questions is not to create/migrate the entire database, the database always exist and most of its tables also exists, but some of the tables may not. So I just need create one or two tables in runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a table exists within a database using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218489/check-if-a-table-exists-within-a-database-using-linq)

Comment: @Guy So you are suggesting that there is no way to do it?

Comment: I suggest you can check if the table exists and create it if it doesn't.

Comment: @Guy Yes, that's a good idea, but how to do that in EntityFramework?

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100969/entity-framework-how-to-check-if-table-exists? there are many examples.

Comment: Ok so check the exists of a table can be done with EFCore elegantly, but create table have to be done with raw sql query? I asked because I want to avoid use sql statement directly in an EFCore application.

Answer (score 11):

In Entity framework Core (on version 2.2.4) you can use the following code in your DbContext to create tables in your database if they don't exist:

```cs
try
{
    var databaseCreator = (Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>() as RelationalDatabaseCreator);
    databaseCreator.CreateTables();
}
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
{
    //A SqlException will be thrown if tables already exist. So simply ignore it.
}
```

Database.EnsureCreated() doesn't create the schema (so your tables) when the database already exists. That's the reason why you get that exception.
You can check that method's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.ensurecreated?view=efcore-3.0).

PS: Make sure you catch the right exception if it changes in the new versions of Entity framework Core.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that your context is wrongly defined. Maybe you forgot to add the DbSet to your context implementation?

Below code is working perfectly, and I honestly prefer to EnsureCreated() in the constructor of the actual DBContext implementation.

```cs
internal class AZSQLDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AZSQLDbContext() {
        this.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    internal DbSet<TaskExecutionInformation> TaskExecutionInformation { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var dbUser = "your-user";
        var dbPW = "your-pw";
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
            $"Server=tcp:sample-sql.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=sample-db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={dbUser};Password={dbPW};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;");
    }
}
```

TaskExecutionInformation is just a PoCo and could be anything. See below though if you need a bit of guidance.

```cs
public class TaskExecutionInformation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This misses the point of handling the case when the database is there but a table is missing from it.  ```this.Database.EnsureCreated();``` simply creates the database when the entire database is missing, and it does not look at the tables of an existing database.

Answer (score 2):

In my case there was 2 applications using same database and those could create its own code-first tables, if they were missing.
So my solution for that is following extension method used in startup on dbcontext:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Infrastructure.Extensions
{
    internal static class DbContextExtensions
    {
        internal static void EnsureCreatingMissingTables<TDbContext>(this TDbContext dbContext) where TDbContext : DbContext
        {
            var type = typeof(TDbContext);
            var dbSetType = typeof(DbSet<>);

            var dbPropertyNames = type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name == dbSetType.Name)
                .Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();

            foreach (var entityName in dbPropertyNames)
            {
                CheckTableExistsAndCreateIfMissing(dbContext, entityName);
            }
        }

        private static void CheckTableExistsAndCreateIfMissing(DbContext dbContext, string entityName)
        {
            var defaultSchema = dbContext.Model.GetDefaultSchema();
            var tableName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(defaultSchema) ? $"[{entityName}]" : $"[{defaultSchema}].[{entityName}]";

            try
            {
                _ = dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"SELECT TOP(1) * FROM {tableName}"); //Throws on missing table
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var scriptStart = $"CREATE TABLE {tableName}";
                const string scriptEnd = "GO";
                var script = dbContext.Database.GenerateCreateScript();

                var tableScript = script.Split(scriptStart).Last().Split(scriptEnd);
                var first = $"{scriptStart} {tableScript.First()}";

                dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(first);
                Log.Information($"Database table: '{tableName}' was created.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't handle dependencies.  It will fail if trying to create a table that has FKs to another table that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here. The simplest is to do:

```
MyContext.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Or, do it initialization style, by putting this in your context's constructor:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>());
```

Both of these however require you to drop your schema manually every time you have modified your model and need to re-create the database. If you don't want to do that, you can use the following initialization instead:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>());
```

This will check your model against the database every time you run your program, and automatically drop and re-create the database if the model has been modified.

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to drop the database, and simply update it, then you can use the following initialization:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Config>());
```

Comment: I'm not creating the database, the db always exists, I just need to create a table if the table does not exists.

Comment: Thanks, but when I tried the your example, the `SetInitializer` method does not exists in EFCore: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade

Comment: It looks the method is removed in latest version of EFCore.

Comment: @fluter Yes, I hadn't noticed you were using EF Core. Unfortunately, MS have removed automatic migrations in EF Core, and don't plan to implement them at all.

Comment: This answer no longer appears to be applicable to the latest version of EFCore.