# EnsureCreated method cannot create new tables in db

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm using `context.Database.EnsureCreated();` to map and create automatically tables considering their entities on Mac OS. But, it doesn't create new tables for new entities newly created.

When I run the following codes, I see 3 tables in the db. But when I add `Battle.cs` and uncomment -

```
public DbSet<Battle> Battles { get; set; }
```

in `DbContext`, the `context.Database.EnsureCreated();` call doesn't create the `Battle` table in database.

Models -

```cs
public class Samurai
{
    public Samurai()
    {
        Quotes = new List<Quote>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
    public Clan Clan { get; set; }
}

public class Clan
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClanName { get; set; }
}

public class Quote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Samurai Samurai { get; set; }
    public int SamuraiId { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext -

```cs
public class SamuraiContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Samurai> Samurais { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Quote>   Quotes   { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Clan>   Clans   { get; set; }
    // public DbSet<Battle> Battles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(@"Server=localhost;port=3306;Database=exercise;Uid=root;Pwd=password;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true;");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

The `Battle` model -

```cs
public class Battle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set;}
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Program -

```cs
class Program
{
    private static SamuraiContext context = new SamuraiContext();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

Comment: EnsureCreated only checks that a database exists. If you want to update a schema you need to create and apply migrations.

Comment: 你可以使用 我这看到的一个 回答 https://stackoverflow.com/a/68065377/19658411 但是可能对于 Table 之间有外键连接的 创建会报错

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Jeremy commented, `EnsureCreated()` simply doesn't do what you want to do. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.ensurecreated?view=efcore-5.0) page:

> Ensures that the database for the context exists. **If it exists, no**
> **action is taken**. If it does not exist then the database and all its
> schema are created. If the database exists, then no effort is made to
> ensure it is compatible with the model for this context.

`EnsureCreated()` is great if for example you're integration testing on an in-memory SQLite database.

Normally you want to generate a schema for the current model by running `dotnet ef migrations add <MigrationName>`, and then if you want to programmatically ensure that the database reflects the current schema, call `database.Migrate()`. Of course you can also call `dotnet ef database update` from the cli.

**That said**, if you're working with a throwaway database of some sorts, and you don't want to bother at all with generating schema or migrations, then ...

```csharp
database.EnsureDeleted();
database.EnsureCreated();
```

... should work fine, because these `Ensure*` methods don't rely on migrations.

*(I just tested it by adding an extra entity to a `DbContext`, then calling `EnsureDeleted()` followed by `EnsureCreated()` without a prior migration, and it indeed recreated the database, with a table for the new entity as well.)*

If you have additional questions, feel free to comment, and I'll address them. :)