# C# SqlCeException: One Line SQL to determine table exists

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

Following the guidelines presented in [SO Question #167576](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576), I constructed the following SQL query string in my **C# WinForm application** to determine if table `RMCoil` exists:

```
using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(null, new SqlCeConnection(Connection))) {
  cmd.Connection.Open();
  cmd.CommandText =
    "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='RMCoil') " +
    "SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0";
  if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() < 1) {
    // code to create table
  }
}
```

Executing the non query throws this `SqlCeException`:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = IF ]

I'm fairly new to SqlCeServer. Could someone enlighten me on how to execute this query all in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='RMCoil')` might do the trick?
You would also have to do `ExecuteScalar()` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()` I think to retrieve your value...

As Paul Sasik very wisely pointed out, the following query is even better:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='RMCoil'`

Comment: +1 but could be simpler. If you use `Execute Scalar` then your query could be: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='RMCoil'` If you get 0 then there's no such table. If you get 1 then yes.

Comment: @Paul Very true. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: [+1] Ugh! I'd thought about `ExecuteScalar()` when I originally wrote the code, but thought I'd try `ExecuteNonQuery()` first. When I got the error, I forgot!

Comment: Actually, Paul, `SELECT COUNT(*)...` returns 1 every time, it's just all values are `NULL`.

Comment: **This works!** `"SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='RMCoil'"`

Answer (score 0):

This actually made a better test:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='RMCoil') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```