# Deploy Database Project Script Erroinr

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, database-connection

We are a team working on a project, and one of our teammates created the database and included the script to create the tables , I am using sql server and I set the properties to my local database but when I hit deploy the PREDEPLOYMENT.SQL I get a bunch of syntax error,

```
The syntax check failed 'Incorrect syntax near `.' in the batch near:
Error   383 SQL80001: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected.   ...\Pre-Deployment\Script.PreDeployment.sql 228
```

Don't understand why I am getting all these syntax errors

Comment: We can't understand either without seeing at least part of your sql script. The best I can guess is that somewhere you have improper syntax.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/685/56820843.jpg/

Comment: Perhaps you could show a line of the code (**in your question NOT as an image** that corresponds to the error included **IN** your question. (Somewhere around line 228?)

Comment: Sorry, this is line 228 : CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `referer`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/sql-server-check-if-table-exists

Answer (score 0):

From the question referenced in my comment above, I believe the SQL Server syntax you are looking for is:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TheSchema' AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable'))
BEGIN
    --Do Stuff
END
```