# SQL get table row count for specific table in DB

Tags: sql, count, sp-msforeachdb

How Can i iterate thru the all my DB's and get a row count for each employee table?
Each client is has there own DB, need to find the total employees in each DB.

Been trying to figure out how to use **sp_MSforeachdb**

```
sp_MSforeachdb 
@command1 = 'select count(*) from employee'
```

Can output in seperate tables or would be good in one table wiht the DB name.

Comment: Almost all the DB's are the same, only one is different has no employee table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000)
    SET @sql = 'Use [?];'
      + 'IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''dbo'' AND  TABLE_NAME = ''employee''))'
      + ' BEGIN'
      + ' SELECT COUNT(*) from [employee]'
      + ' END'
   exec sp_MSforeachDB @sql
```

TABLE_SCHEMA = ''dbo'' is optional here in most cases...

Comment: Thanks to [joew's blog](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx) for syntax for "use [?];" and to [akmad on another stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/sql-server-check-if-table-exists) for the check if a table exists.

Comment: Thanks very much. I also added to mine ''?'' to the select. SELECT ''?'',COUNT(*)  to get the table names. Those are single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it which database to use first (it's in `?`):

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
@command1='use ?; select count(*) from employee'
```