# SQLite delete from only if the table exists

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Right now I have this statement

```
DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence where name = 'table_name';
```

which works fine in most cases, but now I have a case where the `sqlite_sequence` table is not being created and so I get back

```
no such table: sqlite_sequence
```

I need a statement that only does the delete if the table exists. I've found this statement to tell me if the table exists or not

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

But so far I've been unable to successfully pair it with the delete satement

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803679/delete-row-if-table-exists-sql

Comment: great link, but unfortunately I'm not seeing any solutions that work with SQLite

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The table existence check should include the name, of course

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table_name';
```

But you'll have to do it from the calling application in separate statements, i.e. run the above, and based on the count (naturally 1=true, 0=false) as boolean value, you can proceed to run the **DELETE** statement.

Comment: Although I was looking for a way to do it in a single statement, I'm making this the solution since there doesn't seem to be a way in SQLite to do this in a single statment

Comment: You can just use `SELECT 1 ...` instead of `COUNT(*)`