# Delete records from table if table exists

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of delete queries but in some production databases some table is not found. I need simple decision on this problem.

Queries like

```
DELETE b.* FROM `table` b
JOIN `another_table` u
ON u.key2 = b.key
WHERE u.key3 <> ?
```

I need something like:

```
IF TABLE `table` EXISTS DELETE b.* FROM `table` b ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to delete the rows of a table if that latter exists, you will have to rely on a custom stored procedure I think. something like that:

```
-- Define the procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_if_exists(IN tbl CHAR(80))
BEGIN
    IF @tbl IN (select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = "db_2_44afb7")
    THEN
        SET @query = CONCAT("DELETE FROM ", @tbl);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
        EXECUTE stmt;
    END IF;
END //

-- use it
CALL delete_if_exists("mytable");
CALL delete_if_exists("myothertable");
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ee190/3 for an example.
Of course, you could adjust the `"DELETE FROM",...` part to fit with your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose the SELECT query on the table before using the DROP...

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT table.records FROM table WHERE ...)
      DELETE records_names FROM ...
```

From what it sounds like IF EXISTS(select query here) before your delete command is what you're looking for? I'm a postgresql guy so please excuse the SQL errors if they exist.

More examples in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803679/delete-row-if-table-exists-sql).

Comment: I don't want delete table.  I just need to delete records from table