# check if table exists sql server

Tags: java, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server: Check if table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/sql-server-check-if-table-exists)

I'm working with Java and MS SQL Server 2008 and I want to create a table only after checking if it not already exists in the database.

```
 public void addTestTable(){
  jdbcTemplate.execute(
            "create table [mydatabase].[dbo].[test] (ID integer not null identity, CREATEDBY varchar(50), CREATEDAT datetime, TITLE varchar(50), NRQUEST int, FORGROUP int, primary key(id))"

            );
```

}

This is my createTable function, I need another boolean function for checking if the table already exists, but I don't know how to write the sql statement for it. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/sql-server-check-if-table-exists

Answer (score 2):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tablename','U') is not null
-- table exists
```

or

```
SELECT *
   FROM sys.tables
   WHERE name = 'mytable'
   AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('myschema')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testSchema' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'testTable')
BEGIN
    --create table
END
```

Comment: is `!` a valid operator for T-SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if not exists(select 1 from sys.tables where name ='test' and schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo'))
begin
  create table [dbo].[test] (ID integer not null identity, CREATEDBY varchar(50), 
  CREATEDAT datetime, TITLE varchar(50), NRQUEST int, FORGROUP int, primary key(id)) 
  print 'table created'
end
go
```