# how to drop and create a table in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which will create a new table `table1A%yyyymm%` by duplicating the structure of an old table, `table1`. But before I create the new table, I need to check if the table exist or not, if exists, I need to drop the table first. Here is my stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @yyyymm char(6)
SET @yyyymm=CONVERT(nvarchar(6), GETDATE(), 112)


DECLARE @tableName varchar(50)
SET @tableName='table1A_' + @yyyymm 

DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tableName

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE type='u' and name =@tableName)
EXEC(@SQL) print (@sql)


SET @SQL= 'SELECT TOP 0 * 
INTO ' + @tableName + ' FROM table1 with (nolock)'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

But if the table exists, I always got an error like following. Where is wrong?

```
DROP TABLE table1A_201404
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named 'table1A_201404' in the database.
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/sql-server-check-if-table-exists

Comment: Why would you want to create a table in your stored procedure. Is there  reason why you don't use temp tables?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using "with NOLOCK"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had me stumped...  Seems the "If Exists" does not work well together with exec in this case.  Updated script below:

```
DECLARE @yyyymm char(6)
SET @yyyymm=CONVERT(nvarchar(6), GETDATE(), 112)

DECLARE @tableName varchar(50)
SET @tableName='table1A_' + @yyyymm 

DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tableName

EXEC('IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE type=''u'' and name = N''' + @tablename + ''') DROP TABLE table1A_201404')

SET @SQL= 'SELECT TOP 0 * 
INTO ' + @tableName + ' FROM sysobjects with (nolock)'
EXEC(@SQL) print @SQL
```