# How can I implement this plan in C# with SQL command?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables:

- Table 1 with columns `name_markaz nvarchar(100)`, `code_markaz nchar(20)`;
- Table 2 with columns `name_markaz nvarchar(100)`, `code_markaz nchar(20)`;

I want implement this plan, read all data from table 1 and insert into table 2 with this condition:

```
if table1.code_markaz not found in table 2.code_markaz then

   insert the table1.code_markaz into the table2.code_markaz
```

Comment: you want this in sql query

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if table exists in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

I think this query can do that (I prefer using `EXISTS`):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (name_markaz, code_markaz)
   SELECT name_markaz, code_markaz 
   FROM table1
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM table2 ti
                     WHERE ti.code_markaz = table1.code_markaz);
```

Comment: This is one line command and you can execute it from c# easily ;).

Comment: column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON. i get that error

Comment: If you have any IDENTITY column after `SELECT` you should remove them in the insert statements ;).