# How to check if a projection exists before dropping it in Vertica?

Tags: sql, ddl, vertica

I want to do something like

```
DROP PROJECTION IF EXISTS myProjection;
```

Apparently I can use **IF EXISTS** for a table but not a projection.

I understand if I drop the table with CASCADE, that should drop the corresponding projections, but I apparently have some orphaned projections which I do not have a track of. And sometimes when I rename tables/projections, it fails saying projection already exists.

[The Drop Projection page](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/DROPPROJECTION.htm) and [this stackoverflow page for generic sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server) do not help much.

Edit: I am using this in Mybatis Migrations. So my entire migration would fail if there is an error in any of the scripts. So, no I can not ignore the error.

If there is no IF EXISTS for a projection -- is there a programatic way (LIKE TSQL/PLSQL) where I could specify a condition to check if the projection exists and take an action whether to drop it or not?

Comment: You can check the system view `projections` for the presence of a projection

Comment: https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/GET_PROJECTION_STATUS.htm

Comment: @Hogan GET_PROJECTION_STATUS would throw an error if the projection does not exist. I just confirmed it my running: SELECT GET_PROJECTION_STATUS('myProjection');

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Considering that there is no If statement in vertica, I am not sure how to exactly frame the script. I tried with the [case statement](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/LanguageElements/Expressions/CASEExpressions.htm) but did not seem like the way to go.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details about your process? Why don't you simply issue a `DROP` and ignore the error?

Comment: @mustaccio: My process is a mybatis migration script, which will fail the entire migration if there is an error in the script. You say I can 'ignore' the error, do you mean programmatically (like a 'ignore' command)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `drop projection IF EXISTS ...`. You can just use `drop projection ...` and - of course - you will get an error message if the projection you're trying to delete does not exists.

You can list ALL projections for a given schema/table using a SQL like this:

```
\set schema '''my_schema'''
\set table '''my_table'''
select
    projection_name,
    sum(row_count) as row_count, 
    sum(used_bytes) as used_bytes,
    sum(wos_row_count) as wos_row_count, 
    sum(wos_used_bytes) as wos_used_bytes, 
    sum(ros_row_count) as ros_row_count, 
    sum(ros_used_bytes) as ros_used_bytes
from
    projection_storage 
where 
    anchor_table_schema = :schema and
    anchor_table_name = :table
group by 1
order by 1
;
```

And the following will list all projections associated with tables in a given schema:

```
\set schema '''my_schema'''
select
    projection_name,
    anchor_table_name,
    sum(row_count) as row_count, 
    sum(used_bytes) as used_bytes,
    sum(wos_row_count) as wos_row_count, 
    sum(wos_used_bytes) as wos_used_bytes, 
    sum(ros_row_count) as ros_row_count, 
    sum(ros_used_bytes) as ros_used_bytes
from
    projection_storage 
where 
    anchor_table_schema = :schema
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2
;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can query catalog table in vertica, this will give you schema names of all present schemas ,

```
select v_catalog.columns from v_catalog.columns;
```

i sometime use this select query , which gives me evey info related to a table

```
select export_objects('','your_schema.table_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible since Vertica 9.2.x.

```
DROP PROJECTION IF EXISTS myProjection;
```

Reference: https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/DROPPROJECTION.htm