# Auto Switch Database in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, automation

I have an Application that provide web service, but i had a problem with the database. The problem is, my database will always update each day so my `dba` creates another `db` to backup the first `db`. lets say my first `db` name is `db01` and the backup name is `db02`. is there any way to make autogenerate while the `db01` was update and i use `db02` to wait `db01` finished to update?

Comment: Can you not ask your DBA to generate a new table and do a quick rename on them when it's done? Renaming is practically instant.

Comment: Is that possible? My database is using sql server. And my dba said its not possible. @kalkran

Comment: I'm sorry, I read "database" but understood "table" as they're unfortunately used interchangeably. If it's just about tables, they're easy to rename, databases I'm not sure.

Comment: Hmm, thats so sad to know "not sure" @kalkran

Comment: How would you know that `db01` is updating? Can you make a check in your application? Maybe if you're unable to connect to `db01` you can fall back to `db02` ?

Comment: The dba said that he will make 1 table that provide me to know the db01 is done with update and he said will add 1 in the table field. @kalkran

Comment: There is your answer/solution, connect to `db01` by default, check if the table exists and if it does, disconnect and reconnect to `db02`.

Comment: The logic is good, but how should i do it? Im using codeigniter 3. @kalkran

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following, don't forget to substitute the proper variables and the table name in the query.

```
// https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html
$config = [
    'hostname'  => 'localhost',
    'username'  => 'username',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'database'  => 'db01',
    'dbdriver'  => 'mysqli',
]
$conn = $this->load->database($config);
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME="TheTable"');
if ($query->num_fields() > 0) {
    $config['database'] = 'db02';
    $conn = $this->load->database($config);
}
```

*DISCLAIMER: I've never used CodeIgniter.*

Comment: thanks for the solution. from the guide i read, i guess i must create the connection for each model in code i wrote. am i right?