# postgres: syntax error at or near "BEGIN"

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I read this post [Check if table exists in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server)

and wrote this script:

```
do $$
begin

IF (EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'st'
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'config_change_log'))
BEGIN
   CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION st
   CREATE TABLE st.config_change_log
(
  id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  last_config_version varchar(255),
  is_done Boolean,
  chage_description varchar(255)
)

END

end
$$
```

however when I run:

```
psql -h localhost -d myDb -U myUser -f myScript.sql
```

I get this error:

```
psql:myScript.sql:21: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
```

Comment: SQL Server <> Postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much easier in Postgres, no need for an `IF`:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS st;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS st.config_change_log
(
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  last_config_version varchar(255),
  is_done Boolean,
  chage_description varchar(255)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`IF` blocks look like this:

```
IF <condition>
THEN
   <statements>
[ELSIF <condition>
THEN
   <statements>]
[ELSE
   <statements>]
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it this you are looking for?

```
DO $$
BEGIN

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'st'
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'config_change_log'))
THEN
    CREATE SCHEMA st;
    CREATE TABLE st.config_change_log
    (
        id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        last_config_version varchar(255),
        is_done Boolean,
        chage_description varchar(255)
    );
END IF;

END
$$
```