# How do you check a database table existence with query statement

Tags: sql, asp.net

may i know how do you check if a database table already exist in the database already or not with just using the sql query method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if table exists in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`IF Exist(Select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA. COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME like '%tableName%')`