# Procedure run time

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELIMITER $ 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CREATE_BACKUP$
CREATE PROCEDURE CREATE_BACKUP()
BEGIN 
DECLARE BACK INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'STUDENTDB'
;

    SHOW_LOOP:LOOP

        IF BACK = 1 
        THEN  
        LEAVE SHOW_LOOP;
        END IF;

        CREATE TABLE STUDENT_BACKUP 
        AS SELECT * FROM STUDENT;
        CREATE TABLE SCORE_BACKUP 
        AS SELECT * FROM SCORE;
        CREATE TABLE GRADE_EVENT_BACKUP 
        AS SELECT * FROM grade_event;
    END LOOP SHOW_LOOP;

END$
DELIMITER ;
```

Hi, when I run this procedure, it runs more than one time. So I get an error which says "STUDENT_BACKUP table already exists" for the second time when it runs. What should I do to run it just 1 time?

Comment: what do you need the loop for?

Comment: Why is there a `LOOP` in there?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can use `CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXIST...` to avoid the error occurrence. See [CREATE TABLE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) for details. 
To solve your quesrion for SQL server use an `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` view. A similar solution is in the [existing topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/167576/7914637).