# how to write c# code if table not exists create a new table in db with same columns and insert the data

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

Developers, I am new to programming and c# coding I written a code to insert the Xml data into database and it is working perfect but my requirement in code is "if table is not exists create a new table with same columns in the DataBase and insert the data " so how can I write the code ?

```
   public void SaveXmltoDB(List<MeterReading> MeterReadingList)
    {
        //OpenConnection();

       // CreateTableIfNotExists();
        foreach (var meterReading in MeterReadingList)
        {
            foreach(var interval in meterReading.IntervalDatalist)
            {
                foreach(var reading in interval.Readinglist)
                {
                    string command = string.Format("insert into INTERVALDATA1(SerialNumber,TimeStamp,MeterData) VALUES ({0},'{1}',{2})", meterReading.MeterName, reading.TimeStamp.ToString(), reading.RawReading);
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=LAPTOP-N6V52QKD\\AKHIL5656;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=ReportServer$AKHIL5656; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30;" + "persist security info = True;" +
    "Integrated Security = SSPI;"))
                    {

                        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(command,conn);
                        myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                        conn.Open();
                        try
                        {
                            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }

                    }


                }
            }
        }
        CloseConnection();

    }
```

The above code  is perfectly working to insert the data into my table ,In the above code how can I program If table not exists in the database create new table with same columns and insert the data?

can anyone help me on this?

Thanks,

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: You really need to read about parameterized queries. This is vulnerable to sql injection. My friend bobby tables loves code like this. http://bobby-tables.com/ I would also recommend putting your connection strings in the config file instead of hard coded in your application.

Comment: Sql Server 2016 and 13.0 version

Comment: For the question at hand I don't understand the requirements. You are saying if the table doesn't exist then create it with the same columns. That doesn't make sense to me. If the table doesn't exist how would you know what columns to create?

Comment: In the above code My Xml data is directly inserting into the table which was already existing, assuming if the table is not exist in db I have to write a code that if table is not exist create a new table with columns meterdata,timestamp etc..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server With this link and your knowledge of how to create a table, I think you can move forward.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works for SQLServer and MYSQL:

Select * From Information_Schema.Tables Where Table_Name = 'TableName';

This returns all tables matching your name--1 row if the table exists, no rows if it doesn't.

I'm sure the fields returned can be reduced but since it's returning only one row I have never worried about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is summary of a code that I wrote yesterday with a few changes for the answer.
in the beginning the program checks if the table exist, using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.

if the table is not exist it will be create with
`createTableQuery` field that represents the command for creating the new table.
 replace col1 col2 col 3... etc with your columns (SerialNumber,TimeStamp,MeterData... etc) replace the data types and use  `IDENTITY (1, 1)` command if you need incremental value.

```
    private void saveTableToDataBase()
    {
        string tableName = dbTableName;    

        // check if table exist in sql server db
        if (IsTableExistInDb(tableName) == true) {
            // table exist do something...

        } else {
            // create table, replace with your column names and data types
            string createTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE " & "." & tableName & "(" & _
                "ID int  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " & _
                "Col1 int, " & _
                "Col2 decimal(5,4), " & _
                "Col3 int, " & _
                "Col4 decimal(5,4), " & _
                "Col5 int " & _
                ")"
                // create table in database
                Insert(createTableQuery);
        }        
    }


    public static Boolean IsTableExistInDb(string tableName)
    {

        Object result = ExecuteScalarWithAnonimusType("SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = " + "'" + tableName + "'", Con);

        if (result != null && byte.Parse(result.ToString()) == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }    
    }

    public static object ExecuteScalarWithAnonimusType(string query)
    {
        Cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Con);
        try
        {
            return Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {

            if (Con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                Con.Close(); Con.Close();
        }
    }

    public static bool Insert(string command)
    {

        try {
            con = new SqlConnection(System_Vars.SqlClientConnString);
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            return false;

        } finally {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to try and do a create table from string SQL. I mean you could create stored procedure and then call it from code.  But you probably want to do this during application setup program and not when the application runs.