# Checking if a table exists dynamically

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Can someone help me on how to check if a table exists dynamically when the db name,schema name,table name(the table name that has to be checked in that particular dbname and schemaname that was passed) are passed while executing a stored procedure.And so if the table exists then to perform a set of functions else to perform another set of functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if table exists in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server)

Comment: Almost any trivial question has already been asked and been answered at StackOverflow in the past. Just do not hesitate to use Google.

Comment: More than one way but the most concise is `IF OBJECT_ID(N'YourDdatabase.YourSchema.YourTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL`

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/12a74Wf-NEZ5iI1Hz2TtJ7T_2wKqDKxXZCJ6zZAETMAg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This is the method I tried.

Comment: You should concat DB name + '.' + Schema name + '.' + Table name, then execute the IF OBJECT_ID(@YourString) IS NOT NULL and put a BEGIN END afterwards... everything which has to be performed if the table exists goes between this BEGIN AND END...

Comment: Thanks @Tyron78  that worked. (y)

Comment: I added it as answer - it would be really kind of you to accept it. :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should concat DB name + '.' + Schema name + '.' + Table name, then execute the IF OBJECT_ID(@YourString) IS NOT NULL and put a BEGIN END afterwards... everything which has to be performed if the table exists goes between this BEGIN AND END...

Answer (score 2):

The `OBJECT_ID()` function will take a three-part name. So something like:

```
if (OBJECT_ID('db.schema.table') is not null)
   print 'table exists'
else
   print 'table doesn't exist'
```

Answer (score 0):

**For table schema, table name**

Replace print statements with your queries you want to execute :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TableCheck]
    @tableschema VARCHAR(100),
    @tablename VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN

    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @tableschema
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = @tablename))


        BEGIN
            print 'Table '+ @tablename +' Exists';
        END

    ELSE
        print 'Table '+ @tablename +' Does Not Exists';

END
```

output :

```
exec TableCheck dbo, test_table_name
```

Table test_table_name Does Not Exists

In similar manner, you can include database name with little Googling.

**update based on comment** :
Another approach could be

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TableCheck]
    @tableschema VARCHAR(100),
    @tablename VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1 FROM sys.schemas WHERE   name = @tableschema ) 
    BEGIN
        IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.Objects WHERE  Object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tablename) AND Type = N'U'))
            BEGIN
            print 'Table '+ @tablename +' Exists';
            END

        ELSE
            print 'Table '+ @tablename +' Does Not Exists';
    END

    ELSE
        print 'Schema '+@tableschema+' does not exists'
END
```

-----Sean Lange EDIT-------

Prabhat G asked to see how to join sys.objects and sys.schemas

```
select * 
from sys.objects o
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
where o.name = @tablename
    and s.name = @tableschema
```

Comment: You should not use the column TABLE_SCHEMA as reliable source to determine the schema. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql

Comment: Thanks. Will use OBJECT_ID now onwards.

Comment: Nothing wrong with writing a query, especially if you want more information. But you need to query sys.objects and sys.schemas. :)

Comment: @SeanLange : updated my answer with alternate approach. thanks

Comment: You could also join sys.objects to sys.schemas so you can do it in a single query. But this should work anyway.