# How to check if a list of tables exists in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of table names and I want to check whether each one of them exists in database or not. I know how to [check if a table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server), and I can union select expressions for each table name, but there must be an easier solution. This is my current code:

```
select 'TableName1', CASE
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TABLE_NAME 
                     FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                     WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'TableName1') THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         end
union
select 'TableName2', CASE
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TABLE_NAME 
                     FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                     WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'TableName2') THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         end
-- and so on
```

Comment: try this SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' order by TABLE_NAME it give list of table in tha database

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ I don't want list of all tables, I want to know if a list of tables (e.g. `'TN1'`, `'TN2'`, `'TN3'`, ...) exists in DB, I want a flag for each one of them indicating if table exists or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this

```
SELECT 
     table_name,
     CASE WHEN OBJECT_ID(table_name,'U') IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM (VALUES
      ('dbo.table1'),
      ('dbo.table2')) V(table_name)
```

Comment: That's beautiful, I have never seen the FROM syntax used like that before.

Answer (score 1):

To get the EXACT output you specified in your question try this. P.Salmon's answer is much more elegant, but this works for me:-

```
USE MASTER;

DECLARE @tables TABLE(RowNum int Identity, TableName varchar(255), DoesExist bit);
INSERT INTO @tables
SELECT 'Table1',null
UNION
SELECT 'spt_fallback_dev',null

DECLARE @TableName varchar(255), @RowPosition int=0, @TotalRows int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tables)
WHILE (@RowPosition <= @TotalRows)
BEGIN
    SET @RowPosition = @RowPosition + 1;
    SELECT @TableName = (SELECT TableName FROM @tables WHERE RowNum = @RowPosition);

    UPDATE @tables 
    SET DoesExist = (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME=@TableName) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
    WHERE RowNum = @RowPosition;

END

SELECT * FROM @tables;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use intersect and except. For example

```
DROP TABLE #T
CREATE TABLE #T (TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #T VALUES
('MYTABLE'),('TABLE2'),('ZZZ')

print 'IN INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM #T   
INTERSECT
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
print 'NOT IN ONFORMATION SCHEMA'
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM #T   
EXCEPT
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

(3 row(s) affected)
IN INFORMATION_SCHEMA
TABLE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MYTABLE
TABLE2

(2 row(s) affected)

NOT IN ONFORMATION SCHEMA
TABLE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZZZ

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't run it: `Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Arabic_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the INTERSECT operation.`

Comment: Yes, and error message shows that my database uses Arabic collation.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #yourtable (TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100)COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NULL)
    INSERT INTO #yourtable  VALUES
    ('TableName1'),('TableName2'),soon...

    SELECT t.table_name,(case when d.table_name is null then 0 else 1 end) flag FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
    left join #yourtable d on d.table_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS =t.TABLE_NAME COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: Query Updated check it.

Comment: Same problem, just like P.Salmon's answer : `Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Arabic_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.`

Comment: query changed check.

Comment: Well it returns different output than I want, it checks all tables in database to see if they exist in the list, while I need the opposite. By the way, the OP wont get notified if you comment on your posts unless you mention his/her name.

Comment: i think problem in creating in #table, so u try this in actual table.

Comment: The  logic is just left join the tabled named and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES