# How to check if the table exists before inserting data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to make such as: IF (table if exists types) THEN ... END ?

Comment: search for your title on google and you will find tons of solutions to your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if table exists in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = '[database name]' 
AND table_name = '[table name]';
```

Save the result and you can use it in an if statement