# How to copy a table from a linked server into the main database only on the condition that the table does not already exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have the following T-SQL query:

```
USE MyDatabase

INSERT INTO [Table1]
    SELECT *
    FROM [xxx.xx.x.xx].[xxx].[dbo].[Table1]
```

I would like to modify this query so that it copies `Table1` into `MyDatabase` only if that table does not already exist in `MyDatabase`.

I've had a look here but I can't figure out how to migrate the solutions into my problem: [Check if table exists in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
    IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND  TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Table1]
        SELECT *
        FROM [xxx.xx.x.xx].[xxx].[dbo].[Table1]
    END
```

More details and approaches you can read here:
[Check if table exists in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server#167680)

Comment: Isn't that doing the contrary of what I want to achieve? My aim is that if Table1 exists, then it should not start the insert operation. I did not want to run that on my live database so that I do not mess things up. Just trying to confirm if your solution is doing just that.

Comment: Yes you're right, my bad. Just insert a `NOT` before the `EXISTS` that would be a `( NOT EXISTS`, I will edit my post...

Comment: Thanks. Works beautifully.

Comment: I'm surprised that works, in fact I'm confident it wouldn't as there would need to be a `CREATE` script first for the `INSERT INTO` to work. Seem like what you'd really want is a `SELECT...INTO...`.