# Table doesn't exists by table name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible in SQL Server to check whether table exists in this way? If it doesn't exists, it will run catch

```
             declare @SQL  varchar(4444)

             select @SQL = '
             begin try
                select * from ServerName.DBName.dbo.TableNAme
             end try
             begin catch
                select 1
             end catch'

             exec (@SQL)
```

I don't want to use solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server) , because I want to use exact same structure of table as above.

Reason: I will run several dynamic queries in loop, and above ServerName, DbName ,TableName gonna be passed as a parameter.

Comment: Of course I did. Above script doesn't run catch, it throws an error if that object doesn't exist

Comment: you do now that `try ... catch` is a costly operation ? It will slow your loop down

Comment: I have no other choice.

Comment: How exactly do you propose returning a dummy row with the exact same structure as a table if the table no longer exists? Where do you get the structure?

Comment: @SeanLange , see update, i want that dynamic query to run successfully, why catch doesn't run?

Comment: @GuidoG , don't laugh a lot

Comment: The catch doesn't happen because even in dynamic sql it won't parse. That is not a run time error which is what try/catch handles.

Comment: Why not use if exists and look at sys.tables? But still how would you know what the structure would be when the table doesn't exist?

Comment: @SeanLange, sys tables you can't look for db name and servername

Comment: Didn't realize it was a remote server. This sounds a LOT like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: @SeanLange it actually isn't, and pretty straightforward. I for some reason forgot to get out of try catch query itself

Comment: Well if it is an xy problem you wouldn't think it is....that is kind of the definition. But whatever, seems you found a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work if you do it dynamically.   When you don't do it dynamically, the missing table will be caught at parse time, and the CATCH will not be triggered.

EDIT:  I mean like this:

```
         declare @SQL  varchar(4444)

         select @SQL = 'select * from ServerName.DBName.dbo.TableNAme'
         begin try
            exec (@SQL)
         end try
         begin catch
            select 1
         end catch
```

Comment: I updated script. If table doesn't exist, catch doesn't run, it throws an error

Comment: Of course not, you put the CATCH in the dynamic context.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry. I don't know why I missed that