# PostgreSQL check number of tables that match regex

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, count, where-clause

It there a good way to check the number of existing table in the database that matches a particular format?

For example, I am looking for any table names that starts with `'rangtable'`, such as `'rangtable1'`, `'rangtable2'`, `'rangtable3'`....etc, in this case, it returns three.

I am not sure if there is a query or term I need to search for in the SQL realm. Best I came up with is to do a full table query and then do a fetchall (I am using Python with PostgreSQL) than try to do some regex matching with the result.

[Is there a better way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query [the Postgres `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/infoschema-tables.html) :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE table_name LIKE 'rangtable%';
```

If you need to match against a regular expression (which is not the case for the simple pattern you provided), you can use operator `SIMILAR TO`, or better yet POSIX operator `~` :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE table_name ~ '^rangtable';
```

Comment: This works great for number 1-9, for the case where there is a unknown number of digit suffix, would LIKE 'rangtable' cover all cases such as rangtable110 or rangtable001? I imagine something complex like regex is off the table with this kind of query?

Comment: Yes `%` is the wildcard character, it matches any sequence of 0 to N characters.

Comment: ...and if you want more (actually: less) you'll have to think more.