# Check if $tablename exists in SQL Server 2017, CREATE TABLE $tablename if it doesn't exist

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc, sqlsrv

I would like to check if the SQL Server 2017 table $tablename (entered by the user in a PHP form) exists:

```
    try {
        $dothis = "
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N$tablename)
               CREATE TABLE $tablename ( id int IDENTITY (1,1), Name text, GeomCol1 geometry, GeomCol2 AS GeomCol1.STAsText() )";
        $tbl = $pdo->exec($dothis);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
```

But I always get the same error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'NNewTable'.
```

Here too:

```
    try {
        $dothis = "
            IF OBJECT_ID ( $tablename, 'U' ) IS NULL 
            BEGIN 
               CREATE TABLE $tablename ( id int IDENTITY (1,1), Name text, GeomCol1 geometry, GeomCol2 AS GeomCol1.STAsText() )
            END";
        $tbl = $pdo->exec($dothis);
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'NewTable'.
```

No problem creating the table if I don't check to see if the table exists first:

```
    try {
        $dothis = "
               CREATE TABLE $tablename ( id int IDENTITY (1,1), Name text, GeomCol1 geometry, GeomCol2 AS GeomCol1.STAsText() )";
        $tbl = $pdo->exec($dothis);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
```

No error, and it creates the table with name $tablename

I see that there are many different ways to [check if a table exists in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server)

Unfortunately, each time I try to use a $tablename variable to check if the table exists, it returns an error.  I hope someone can help.

Comment: Enclose the table name in single quotes for literals `WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'$tablename'`, `IF OBJECT_ID ( N'$tablename', 'U' ) IS NULL`.

Comment: Yup, that seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the table name in single quotes when used as a literal. Also, consider enclosing the table name in square brackets (or double quotes) if the name might not conform to [rules for regular identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers) (e.g. embedded spaces).

```
try {
    $dothis = "
        IF OBJECT_ID ( N'$tablename', 'U' ) IS NULL 
        BEGIN 
           CREATE TABLE [$tablename] ( id int IDENTITY (1,1), Name text, GeomCol1 geometry, GeomCol2 AS GeomCol1.STAsText() )
        END";
    $tbl = $pdo->exec($dothis);
```

Comment: New to PHP, enclosing a variable name in quotes just feels wrong.  But that's what you gotta do.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
    try {
        $dothis = "
            if not exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = N'$tablename')
            BEGIN 
               CREATE TABLE $tablename ( id int IDENTITY (1,1), Name text, GeomCol1 geometry, GeomCol2 AS GeomCol1.STAsText() )
            END";
        $tbl = $pdo->exec($dothis);
```