# Check if entity already exists in a table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I want to check if entity already exists in a table, I tried to search google from this and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server) , but it didn't help me.
I want to `return False` if the entity already exists but it always insert the user.

```
def insert_admin(admin_name) -> Union[bool, None]:
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT name FROM admin WHERE name='{admin_name}'")
    print(cursor.fetchall()) # always return empty list []
    if cursor.fetchone():
        return False
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO admin VALUES('{admin_name}')") # insert the name

def current_admins() -> list:
    print(cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM admin').fetchall()) # [('myname',)]
```

When I run the program again, I can still see that `print(cursor.fetchall())` return empty `list`. Why is this happening if I already insert one name into the table, and how can I check if the name already exists ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: update `cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO admin (name) VALUES('{admin_name}')") ` and commit need  to call if auto commit is not configured.

Comment: @AshishKarn It is now edit the current `name` and not add a new one. How can I add a new `name` instead of replacing the current `name`? For now as I can see, I can only hold one `name` in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid duplicate names in the table, then let the database do the work -- define a `unique` constraint or index:

```
ALTER TABLE admin ADD CONSTRAINT unq_admin_name UNIQUE (name);
```

You can attempt to insert the same name multiple times.  But it will only work once, returning an error on subsequent attempts.

Note that this is also much, much better than attempting to do this at the application level.  In particular, the different threads could still insert the same name at (roughly) the same time -- because they run the first query, see the name is not there and then insert the same row.

When the database validates the data integrity, you don't have to worry about such race conditions.

Comment: Can you please use uppercase letters instead of lowercase, and what is `unq_admin_name` ? Do I need to replace `unq_admin_name` and `name` with my admin name ?

Comment: @dsasd . . . I don't understand your comment at all.  This creates a constraint in the database.  Once you create it, `name` is guaranteed to be unique in `admin`.

Comment: But I want to able to add many `admins` to the table. Not only one.

Comment: @dsasd . . . Huh?  Of course you can add as many admins as you like.  They just can't have the same name.