# Python 3 failed to check whether the database exists and create it

Tags: python, pymssql

I'm a python beginner. I want to use Python 3 to check the `test2` database on the SQL server. If it doesn't exist, I will create it. However, I find that an error is reported and I don't know what to do?

python code:

```
import pymssql 
 
 
def conn():
    ret = pymssql.connect(host='DESKTOP-4CDQOMR', user = 'sa', password = '123456') 
    if ret:
        print("connect successfully!")
    else:
        print("connect failed!")

    return ret
        

 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = conn()  
    if conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sql = "if not exist (select * from sys.databases where name = 'test2')"
        conn.autocommit(True)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        conn.autocommit(False) 
        conn.close()
```

error information:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MSSQLDatabaseException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
src\pymssql.pyx in pymssql.Cursor.execute()

src\_mssql.pyx in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query()

src\_mssql.pyx in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query()

src\_mssql.pyx in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query()

src\_mssql.pyx in _mssql.check_cancel_and_raise()

src\_mssql.pyx in _mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException()

MSSQLDatabaseException: (156, b"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
F:\jupyter\connect.py in <module>
     20         sql = "if not exist (select * from sys.databases where name = 'test2')"
     21         conn.autocommit(True)
---> 22         cursor.execute(sql)
     23         conn.autocommit(False)
     24         conn.close()

src\pymssql.pyx in pymssql.Cursor.execute()

OperationalError: (156, b"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server probably can help

Comment: @Leo Arad  Sorry, I still can't find the answer I want in it, because it mainly discusses table instead of database

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my question by modifying the follow code :

```
sql = "if not exist (select * from sys.databases where name = 'test2')"
```

to

```
sql = "if not exists (select * from sys.databases where name = 'test2') begin create database test2 end"
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi hope this code below helps u!

```
import mysql.connector

DB_NAME  = "test2"

client = mysql.connector.connect(host = "127.0.0.1",
                                 user = "admin",
                                 passwd = "password")
mycursor = client.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

if DB_NAME in mycursor:    print("Database exists :)")
else :
    print(f"Database {DB_NAME} doesn't exist, creating now....")
    mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE firstdatabase")
    print(f"Database {DB_NAME} created!")
```

Comment: The question is about MS -SQL Server, not MySQL.