# If not exist clause SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I found this sql query in a project I am succeeding. This is the first time I encountering this clause/statement. I understand that this is to look if the table exist before creating one and that Object_ID is the table name that is to be created.
My questions are:
Does sysobject mean the database?
What is the Object property?

I know that it is not the columns inside the table to be created.
The columns are : dtb_color_id and description.

can someone explain this to me. please?

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID('DTB_COLOR') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(ID,'ISUserTable') = 1)

BEGIN
.......some query I understand
END
```

Comment: `sys.sysobjects` is SQL Server specific, MySQL is a different product, please review your tags

Comment: It checks, in a unusual way, if the `[dbo].[DTB_COLOR]` exists in the database. See [here for alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes **sysobject** means database.

The **OBJECTPROPERTY()** function returns information about schema-
scoped objects in the current database. Use this to check if an
object is a table, view, stored procedure, etc. You can also use
it to check if a table has a primary key, foreign key, foreign
key reference, etc.

For more details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/objectpropertyex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

In this scenario it is used to check whether it is user table or
not. The result of the ISUserTable property is 1 when it is user
table otherwise returns 0.

Here the following steps are followed:

- First, it executes the select statement inside the IF Exists
- If the select statement returns a value that condition is TRUE for IF Exists
- It starts the code inside a begin statement

DTB_COLOR - May be a stored procedure

Comment: Why do you post this as code?

Comment: You scratched all the itches I have for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`sysobjects`, `OBJECTPROPERTY` and `OBJECT_ID` are used in **Microsoft SQL Server**. They are part of the SQL Server DMVs and system functions/procedures used to query and manipulate the metadata.

`sys.sysobjects` is simply the list of all objects (tables, views, SPs, functions, etc) on the server in the active database. Please note, that `sys.sysobjects` is deprecated and is only available for backward compatibility. Use `sys.objects` instead

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/system-dynamic-management-views?view=sql-server-ver16

It has (as far as I know) no meaning in MySQL, unless somebody specifically created them.

You can also use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` which is available in MySQL too (however slightly different in different RDBMS).

MSSQL INFORMATION_SCHEMA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

MySQL INFORMATION_SCHEMA: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html

---

SQL Server has no `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` construct, a variation of the mentioned condition is commonly used to imitate that.

This is a way in SQL Server to check if a table exists in the active database and to perform actions according to the result, like creating the table.

`OBJECTPROPERTY` simply checks (in this case) if the table is a user created one.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/objectproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

I would remove the `OBJECTPROPERTY` condition in case the part you understand is a `CREATE TABLE` statement. You don't want to create a table which has a similar name to any system table/view, also you don't want to execute the `CREATE TABLE` if there is a `VIEW` with the same name (table creation will fail)